# How to install object files using CMake

Tags: cmake

There is an object library in CMake:

```
add_library( librevolta_runtime_x86 OBJECT
    crt0.S
    crti.S
    crtn.S
)

install( TARGETS librevolta_runtime_x86 EXPORT revolta
    OBJECTS DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib"
)
```

which is linked to my static library:

```
add_library( revolta STATIC )

target_link_libraries( revolta
PUBLIC
    librevolta-runtime-x86
)

# Install all the revolta headers into include directory and copy the built library
install( TARGETS revolta EXPORT revolta
    FILE_SET HEADERS    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include"
    ARCHIVE             DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib"
)

# Export librevolta targets 
install( EXPORT revolta DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/revolta" )
```

The problem is once the library `revota` is build and installed, the result is:

```
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/objects-Debug/librevolta-runtime-x86/crt0.S.obj
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/objects-Debug/librevolta-runtime-x86/crti.S.obj
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/objects-Debug/librevolta-runtime-x86/crtn.S.obj
```

But I need to make up the installation like:

```
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/crt0.o
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/crti.o
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/crtn.o
```

Note: <CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX> is just the placeholder for the path being specified in the CMake variable.

So I need to:

1. Rename the object files from `*.S.obj` to simple `*.o`
2. Adapt the path so that all the object files are installed into pure `<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/` directory
3. Due to `target_link_libraries(...)` dependency, make up the
   `librevolta_runtime_x86` the member of `revolta` export set

Many thanks to anyone willing to help me. Martin

Comment: A little bit offtopic but you should avoid adding `$[CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` to the `DESTINATION`. Relative destinations (e.g. `lib` or `include`) are always considered to be relative to the install dir, a nice side effect of this is - it makes the package relocatable at install time. To make a package aware of distribution specific installation directories you can use the `include(GNUInstallDirs)` module especially its variables `${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}`, `${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}` and others.

Comment: @vre Thanks for the hint, I can confirm, once ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} is removed, it still refers to the correct directory.

Comment: I've answered one part of your question, but because I'm on the phone - I couldn't bring myself to answer more. If it wont get fully answered by someone else I might get back to it on saturday/ sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The simple macro as promised

```
macro(install_objects OBJFILE_LIST)

foreach(OBJFILE ${${OBJFILE_LIST}})
    # Available since CMake 3.20 you can use get_filename_component
    # To get any specific information you can wish for about a file
    # Before 3.20 you would have to use string(REGEX MATCH ...)
    # get_filename_component(OBJ_DIR ${OBJFILE} DIRECTORY) <-- path
    # get_filename_component(OBJ_EXT ${OBJFILE} EXT) <-- extension
   
    get_filename_component(OBJ_NAME ${OBJFILE} NAME)
    
    # You can uncomment the message to see what you can get 
    # MESSAGE(STATUS "OBJ_DIR: ${OBJ_DIR} OBJ_NAME: ${OBJ_NAME} OBJ_EXT: ${OBJ_EXT}")

    # This is just an example, but you can also use ${OBJ_DIR} for example to specify a better path
    install(FILES ${OBJFILE} DESTINATION [wherever_you_want_them] RENAME "${OBJ_NAME}.o")
endforeach(OBJFILE)

endmacro(install_objects)

#example usage
set(MY_OBJECTS 
    "test.s.obj" 
    "somepath/test2.S.obj" 
    "whatever/whatever/test3.s.OBJ" 
    )
install_objects(MY_OBJECTS)
```

The above `MY_OBJECTS` would give you the following variables:

```
-- OBJ_DIR:  OBJ_NAME: test.s.obj OBJ_EXT: .s.obj
-- OBJ_DIR: somepath OBJ_NAME: test2.S.obj OBJ_EXT: .S.obj
-- OBJ_DIR: whatever/whatever OBJ_NAME: test3.s.OBJ OBJ_EXT: .s.OBJ
```

As you can see it is pretty robust and keeps your `CMakeLists.txt` clean. Just make sure to create your `OBJECT_LIST` using pre-defined variables such as `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`

**This will simplify your object files installs. IMO it also answers both ad1) ad2)**

Ad3) I'm not sure what is your issue here or what exactly is happening, as the question itself is focused on installing objects.

---

Is there any specific reason why you wish to install the intermediate object files? This is an important question because a static library when linked will be unpacked and optimized - take a [look at this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609702/link-with-static-library-vs-individual-object-files).

The `OBJECT` libraries are a useful thing in CMake when you know that some parts of your codebase would be compiled multiple times (due to the fact that it uses the same code). It makes sense to couple these parts into a reusable object library.

**All of this aside**: What you are looking for is

```
INSTALL(FILES file-name.abc DESTINATION dest-folder RENAME file-name.xyz)
```

Comment: Yes, there is an explicit reason why to install object files. The project I am working about is a hobby operating system and the aforementioned object files are used to start the execution in user space. It is specified (even the order of linking of those files) by System V specification. Also the explicit name including the suffix is defined there as *.o (thus the renaming)...

Comment: @MartinKopecký Makes sense and sounds interesting. I would recommend defining your own macro that uses the `INSTALL(FILES...)` - once I'm at a computer I will post one such macro that will make it easier for you.